# python ternary operator behaviour

Tags: python, ternary-operator

when I evaluate the following operation

```
0 if True else 1 + 1 if False else 1
```

it evaluates to 0 however when I write with brackets like

```
( 0 if True else 1 ) + ( 0 if False else 1 )
```

it evaluates correctly to 1 , what is happening in the first case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
0 if True else 1 + 1 if False else 1
```

is actually:

```
(0) if (True) else ((1 + 1) if (False) else (1))
```

which is definitely differs from what you want:

```
((0) if (True) else (1)) + ((1) if (False) else (1))
```

Answer (score 3):

as `ternary operator` is read from `left to right`  and `+` has lower precedence than conditional operators. So, these two are equivalent:

```
>>> 0 if True else 1 + 1 if False else 1
0
>>> 0 if True else ( (1 + 1) if False else 1)
0
```

Answer (score -1):

ternary operator looks like "condition ? value if true : value if false",but it seems that python doesn't support it ,but we can use if-else to replace.The stype is something like "condition if (b_1) else b_2,so you can depend it to match.if b_1 is True,the value is condition,if b_2 is True,the value is b_2.

Comment: a if b else c  is python implementation of ternary operator.

Comment: Python's `value if condition else alternative` *is* ternary operator as you can use it as subexpression.

Comment: I know it,but I think your interpretation is better,and I just want to make the reasons behind the results clear.